# Setting attribute with Angular or Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion

Need to set the attribute (isOpen) of an element. When I "hardcode" the value to true or false it works but when I get the value from the "test" method it sets the value and the icon changes but the accordion doesn't open and close.

```
 _title = d.create('h1')
                    .setClasses(['h2', 'pull-left'])
                    .setAttributes([['id', ++number + "values"], ['ng-click', 'isOpen = test(isOpen)'], ['ng-init', 'isOpen = true']])
                    .setInnerHTML(_titleHtml)
                    .toElement();
```

This is the method it calls:

```
    scope.test = function (isOpen) {
                    isOpen = !isOpen;
                    return isOpen;
   }
```

The compiled code from the inspector is as follows:

[image: Compiled html]

I have read about using $apply and $compile but not sure how to make it work.

Appreciate the help.

UPDATE:

I am including a bit more explanation to help you help me. I need to send the isOpen value to the test method because I need to implement additional logic elsewhere depending on whether the isOpen is true or false at that time.eg: if another button is clicked, if the the accordion is already open do nothing but if closed expand etc

Comment: why do you initialize the value in the template?
Do it in the scope `scope.isOpen = true;` then you don't need the `ng-init`.

Comment: You can update your value using the settor, but Angular will not apply effects until it detect the change. Every change are watched and evaluated inside a loop. Calling $apply would cause the loop to be played, change detected and then.. Effects played.

Comment: @Nico if one need to use $apply means that is doing stuff not completely in the angular way!

Comment: Here we are speaking about a test, so, $apply has to be triggered manually (like in every tests...)

Answer (score 0):

```
_title = d.create('h1')
  .setClasses(['h2', 'pull-left'])
  .setAttributes([['id', ++number + "values"], ['ng-click', 'isOpen=!isOpen'], ['ng-init', 'isOpen=true']])
  .setInnerHTML(_titleHtml)
  .toElement();
```

There is no need to use a method....

Comment: Thanks Nico. That is how the code was originally. I need to send the state and set it in the method because there is additional logic I want to implement in the method that I haven't included here.